# PTV Vissim - change route

Tags: python, ptv-vissim

can you help me to write a script to change the route of the vehicle class based on condition?
I want to change the route of a certain vehicles after number of labs at route to another routes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Most of the Vissim community exchanges happen on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/groups/2524087). So you might get faster answers there. Or you could also contact PTV's technical support.